# Does adding a texture to a vector image make it a raster image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, texture, raster

I have managed to create a good looking vector model in Illustrator and I want to improve it by adding some textures. Will this make my model a raster image and no longer a vector?

Comment: But be careful in Photoshop the deal is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Illustrator file you can have both vector shapes and raster images. Saving this artwork as AI will not transform your raster elements to vector. So any image/photo/texture included in an AI file stays raster, and this will not affect your *model* (artwork) which will be saved as vectors. In the end your AI file will contain both vector and raster objects.

Comment: What if I then made my image bigger?..Will it lose quality?

Comment: You can use high resolution images/textures. They will still be raster, not vector, but will print better than low resolution images, if that's your concern.

Comment: @MrCSS depends on the texture. Textures in a vector application can be placed and scaled again. so you might or might not.

Comment: @MrCSS: joojaa is correct re: re-placing the textures, but if you mean a "fixed file that cannot be altered," then "yes" you will lose quality. If you have a hybrid vecotr image that has a 300px square texture and set up the file to print such that the texture is 1inch square, you have an effective resolution for that texture of 300ppi. The vector portion of that hybrid image is going to be whatever the resolution of the output device is. At 10x print size, your effective ppi for the texture is 1/10 (or 30 in this example), the vector output resolution is still whatever the output device is.

Comment: Also note the effect depends heavily on the texture, if its something soft and rolling then being clipped by say a path will make high contrast edges sharp and the interior is smooth anyway so it wont change much by interpolation.

Comment: @joojaa I will be using the vector in my app..The vector will increase/decrease in size depending on the screen size so I am concerned if the image is going to lose quality..I will be using a brick texture from textures.com

Comment: @MrCSS yes but you do not describe where you use it and how big the texture is.

Comment: If the texture is at least 1920x1080 and will not grow more than it's original resolution, then you would probably be fine on _most_ monitors. (There are higher quality ones out there now, so you could still get issues on bigger monitors). If it's 1920x1080 but it never reaches it's full size, then it could even work on higher resolution monitors. As joojaa pointed out -- it all depends on texture size and grow amount. (note 1920x1080 is kind of just an arbitrary amount I chose)

Comment: @Johannes, joojaa, Lucian, Yorik Thank you very much !..I get it now :)